# How to start and stop spring scheduled job?

Tags: spring-boot, scheduling

I have requirement to run a job, generally speaking, from TUE-SAT every 5 minutes but stop the job under some conditions till the end of the day(00h:00mUTC) and start it again next day(00h:00mUTC)
e.g
TUE- job starting to process every 5 minutes but as soon as some condition occurs job has to stop till the end of the day
WED-job has to start to process as long as some condition occurs

Is that possible to achieve?

Comment: You could add a REST API end point to make it ignore the job, or a database setting, but I'd do it in the OS where it's easier to switch the cron on and off.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do it all in Spring, something like this may work, not tested:

A Service like:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Service
public class MyService {

    private boolean pause = false;

    @Scheduled(cron = "*/5 * * * * TUE-SAT")
    public void doStuff() {
        if (LocalTime.now().isAfter(LocalTime.MIDNIGHT)) {
            pause = false;
        }
        if (pause) {
            return;
        }
        System.out.println("do stuff");
    }
}
```

A controller like this:

```
@RestController
public class Controller {

    @Autowired
    private MyService service;

    @PutMapping("/pause")
    public void pause() {
        service.setPause(true);
    }
}
```

To pause the job

```
curl --request PUT http://localhost:8080/pause
```